# How to add onRefresh on inverted FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

i am trying to add pull on refresh on inverted flatlist, the pull works in downwards only in inverting flatlist, the folling problem use case will be in chat where user try to refresh by pulling up in inverted flatlist.